# Tkinter ttk radiobutton variable update failure

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, ttk

What's wrong with this?

```
var = StringVar()
radBut1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='A - Z', variable=var, value='AtoZ')
radBut2= ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='Z - A', variable=var, value='ZtoA')
```

When I select either of the 2 radiobuttons, the var variable is not updated. I found a lot of conflicting material in different documentation sources and tutorials (and I tried everything I found) to no avail.

I'm using the following to check the value of var:

```
print(var)
```

Comment: How do you check the value? Does `print` run in a thread / timer function? Please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: It works. Try print(var.get()) to get the content of var. You may initialize var with var=StringVar(value='AtoZ') if needed

Comment: Thanks for confirming that that works for you Jal. It's not the case for me, maybe because of what nostradamus predicted :)

Comment: Nostradamus: Yes the radiobuttons are on a separate thread from the rest of the application. This is because the amount of data can be large and while the treeview is refreshing the user should be able to continue reviewing other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def updateRadioButtonVariable(radioButtonVar,updateString):
    radioButtonVar.set(updateString)

#Sort Type Radio Button
radioButtonVar = StringVar()
radBut1= ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='A - Z', variable=radioButtonVar, value='AtoZ',command= lambda: updateRadioButtonVariable(radioButtonVar ,'AtoZ'))
radBut2= ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='Z - A', variable=radioButtonVar, value='ZtoA',command= lambda: updateRadioButtonVariable(radioButtonVar ,'ZtoA'))
```

Not sure why the original code (which is almost template code from the documentation) doesn't work. If anyone has any ideas, please do share.